# Difference in performance: Class variable and method variable

Tags: c#, performance, unity-game-engine

Is there a difference in performance with these two methods? One is creating local method variables and the other uses class variables.

```
public float damping = 10f;

void RotateToMousePointer()
{
    Vector3 dir = _shipControls.GetMousePostionInWorldSapce() - transform.position;
    float angle = Mathf.Atan2(dir.y, dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90;
    Quaternion q = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, q, Time.deltaTime * damping);
}

Vector3 dir;
float angle;
Quaternion q;
void RotateToMousePointer2()
{
    dir = _shipControls.GetMousePostionInWorldSapce() - transform.position;
    angle = Mathf.Atan2(dir.y, dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90;
    q = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, q, Time.deltaTime * damping);
}
```

Comment: First rule of "perfomance" questions: test it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is some difference in performance caused by `float angle;` variable here.

Since `float` is value type then `angle` will be stored:

- in `stack` when declared as local variable of method;
- in `heap` when declared as instance field.

From the performance point of view using stack is slightly faster then heap.

But in real application you will not "feel the difference".

Comment: The whole "stack vs. heap" argument, while most likely true in this case, isn't always so. Read Eric Lippert's blog post on the topic (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. The only difference is is that `dir`, `angle` and `q` are not accessible outside the method when using the first approach. If you don't need to access them elsewhere, stick to that one.

Comment: In fact, there is a tiny performance difference here. Consider storage location of `angle` variable - stack in first case and heap in second.